# Am I an Automorphic Number?

Tags: code-golf, number, decision-problem

An Automorphic number is a number which is a suffix of its square in base 10.  This is sequence [A003226](https://oeis.org/A003226) in the OEIS.

### Your Task:

Write a program or function to determine whether an input is an Automorphic number.

### Input:

An integer between 0 and 10^12 (inclusive), that may or may not be an Automorphic number.

### Output:

A truthy/falsy value indicating whether or not the input is an Automorphic number.

### Examples:

```
0           -> truthy
1           -> truthy
2           -> falsy
9376        -> truthy
8212890625  -> truthy
```

### Scoring:

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), lowest score in bytes wins.

Comment: Btw the limit of 1e12 means submissions will need to handle numbers up to 1e24, which is an 80-bit number. If handling numbers that large is a hard requirement, many of the exiting answers are invalid.

Comment: Need we handle numbers that would lead to precision issues in our chosen language?

Comment: Provided that you don't abuse the standard loophole about that, then that would be fine.

Comment: Specifically, [this loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default/8245#8245)

Comment: It's been a loooong day and I am very, very tired but your comments read to me as validating my JS solution. Could you confirm that? (No issue deleting if not)

Comment: Consider that confirmed.  10^9 (which is what I'm pretty sure your program stops working after) is good enough.  I just don't want things that only work on numbers up to, say 1,000.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 5 bytes

```
~√a₁?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/v@5Rx6zER02N9v//WxqbmwEA)

### How it works

```
~√a₁?
~√      the input is the square root of a number
  a₁    whose suffix is
    ?   the input
```

Comment: No, it says if x is a suffix of its square.

Comment: `√a₁?` Why not?

Answer (score 40):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

```python
lambda n:`n*1L`in`n**2L`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBDsIgEEX3c4pZlsYFYKxtk96gN6iNoIKS6LQBNp4eaVn4Nu8vXv76ja@FZLLDJb315/bQSL2iWozKUXYtR5WiCfF618EEHHACzPDDLlEki7rjuSmrlUK2HW/kCWYAu3h06Aj/R/2erd5RRFs5BlD2RLjVtNVe09NUgm8wdDaHxOb0Aw)

For the first time in history, Python 2's appending an `L` to the repr of longs is a feature rather than a bug.

The idea is to check if say, `76^2=5776` ends in `76` by checking if `76L` is a substring of `5776L`. To make the `L` appear for non-huge numbers, we multiply by `1L` or have `2L` as the exponent, since an arithmetic operation with a long with produces a long.

Answer (score 9):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes

Out-golfed by xnor... (this happens every single time) >< But hey, it's surprisingly Pythonic for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

People don't tend to remember Python has `str.endswith()`...

```python
lambda n:str(n*n).endswith(`n`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqrikSCNPK09TLzUvpbg8syRDIyEvQfN/SWpxSXxyYnFqsYKtQjSXAhAY6IApQwhlBKEsjc3NICwLI0MjC0sDMyNTrlgurrT8IoVMhcw8BYRBVmBlBUWZeSUKaRqZmv8B)

Comment: Can't you use `\`n*n\`` to convert number into string?

Comment: @Downgoat That tacks an 'L' on to longer numbers.

Comment: @totallyhuman Good point, I missed its use.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
n.s¹å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/T6/40M7DS///tzQ2NwMA)

Comment: I'd upvote If I knew how it worked.

Comment: I suppose, `n` is square, `.s` is suffixes, `¹` is the input, and `å` tests for membership @isaacg

Comment: @isaacg What Conor said...didn't have time to add explanation.

Answer (score 5):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 44 bytes

```
$
;918212890625;81787109376;0;1;
^(\d+;).*\1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fhcva0tDCyNDIwtLAzMjU2sLQ3MLc0MDS2NzM2sDa0JorTiMmRdtaU08rxvD/f5AwAA)

There are exactly 4 solutions to the 10-adic equation `x*x = x`.

Comment: Uh? Aren't all [these numbers](https://oeis.org/A003226) valid solutions?

Comment: @Leo No, they aren't. Obviously `5*5 != 5`. However, you can notice some pattern in the numbers you linked to. The 4 solutions are: 0, 1, ...59918212890625, ...40081787109376 (p-adic numbers go infinitely to the *left*). The numbers you linked to are suffixes of the 4 numbers.

Comment: Oh ok, thank you, I didn't know about p-adic numbers

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, <s>37</s> <s>33</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

```
lambda n:n*~-n%10**len(`n`)<1
```

Saved 4 bytes thanks to @LeakyNun.
Saved 3 bytes by noticing that the input is lower than 10^12 so `n` doesn't end with an "L".
Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dennis because I miscounted in the first place.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/pfUJSZV6KQlplTklqk8T8nMTcpJVEhzypPq043T9XQQEsrJzVPIyEvQdPG8L@OQlFiXnqqhqEBGGhq/gcA) (TIO link courtesy of @Dennis).

Answer (score 4):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 17 bytes

```
/o.z/#Q/
@in.*.L\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/18/X69KXzlQn8shM09PS88n5v9/czMA)

Outputs nothing (which is falsy in Ordinal mode) or `Jabberwocky` (which is non-empty and therefore truthy in Ordinal mode; it's also the canonical truthy string value).

#### Explanation

```
/.../#./
....*..\
```

This is a slight modification of the general framework for linear Ordinal mode programs. The `/` in the middle is used to have a single operator in Cardinal mode in between (the `*`) and then we need the `#` to skip it in Ordinal mode on the way back. The linear program is then:

```
i..*.QLzno@
```

Let's go through that:

```
i    Read all input as a string and push it to the stack.
..   Make two copies.
*    This is run in Cardinal mode, so it implicitly converts the top two
     copies to their integer value and multiplies them to compute the square.
.    Implicitly convert the square back to a string and make a copy of it.
Q    Reverse the stack to bring the input on top of the two copies of its square.
L    Shortest common supersequence. This pops the input and the square from
     the top of the stack and pushes the shortest string which begins with
     the square and ends with the input. Iff the square already ends with the
     input, this gives us the square, otherwise it gives us some longer string.
z    Drop. Pop the SCS and the square. If the square contains the SCS (which
     would mean they're equal), this removes everything up to the SCS from
     the square. In other words, if the SCS computation left the square
     unchanged, this gives us an empty string. Otherwise, it gives us back
     the square.
n    Logical not. Turns the empty string into "Jabberwocky" and everything
     else into an empty string.
o    Print the result.
@    Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 31 bytes

```
Mod[#^2,10^IntegerLength@#]==#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00sychMLv6fZvvfNz8lWjnOSMfQIM4zryQ1PbXIJzUvvSTDQTnW1lZZ7X9AUWZeiYJDmoKDqaWloYWRoZGFpYGZkel/AA) Mathics prints an extra message but the answer is correct

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, 22 bytes

```ruby
->n{"#{n*n}"=~/#{n}$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vWkm5Ok8rr1bJtk4fyKpV0a/9H82loGCgAyQMQYQRiLA0NjcD0RZGhkYWlgZmRqZcsXqpickZCtUKNXk1CgWlJcUKiopp0XmxCrX/AQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 57 bytes

```c
f(__int128 n){n=n*n%(long)pow(10,printf("%u",n))==n;}
```

Based on @betseg's answer, this is a function that returns **1** or **0**. It produces garbage output to STDOUT, which is [allowed by default](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9658/12012).

The score contains **+4 bytes** for the compiler flag `-lm`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9NasQwDIXX0SlESordSZ1kVoX8nKQwuE48MThy8NjtYpizp6Ltpto8CYnv6X3o23oYnXBCnVPYQtxXZ5TBYUB1WHG5OErd@Q1J3mmkF6qED3SVe/gSXVvvkddWlFUua5JyHKl/HE@OjM/zgsMtzS6odQLgM9y0IyHhDoUNEX84SDhi27MM2LW/xdPpJKEonEVhBWO5L@yfFSOXGGssq/mdypr/6uEBCuBqDL767X8MUI1WISc8T88dZ2zm5bOh7P3xDQ)

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <strike>12</strike> 11 bytes

```
Ｉ¬⌕⮌ＩＸＩθ²⮌θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWH1jzqmfpoXQ@Q@X7PDiB5bsehTUD@uR3//1sam5sBAA)

Returns `False` as `falsey` and `True` as `truthy`.

- 1 byte saved thanks to ASCII-only! (How could I miss the `Power` function?)

Comment: This returns `0` for `10`, `100`, ... `1` for `50`, `60`... `2` for `760`, `3792`...

Comment: @Neil fixed now, thanks!

Comment: I thought Charcoal was only good for ASCII art. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: [11 bytes](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5///9npWH1jzqmfpoXQ@Q@X7PDiB5bsehTUD@uR3//1sam5sBAA)

Comment: @totallyhuman It still is, look at all the normal golflangs with <6 byte solutions

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 47 bytes

```cs
n=>$"{BigInteger.Multiply(n,n)}".EndsWith(n+"")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1Bq8IwEITv/RVL8ZDyNBdFeVQ9KAqCiqjgOaRrXWg3kk0Fkf722gqCc5sZ5hsrA@s8NpUQ53B6SsAyjX6d3lclerKSRrYwInDwLvemfEUAEkwgCw9HGewMsUq6FGBdsZ1uOIxH/YVzBRqewxVmDc/mvfi1oLztMEevd1UR6F48Ffc5qWO94kwuFG6K/@I4aTpW@iEuHUsL0hdPAdVVtf6BPuiz@9yob39Ek22JUSWtumkd1c3/cDJ@Aw)

Comment: Isn't is possible to change `$"{n}"` to `n+""`? Also, could you perhaps add a [TryItOnline-link](https://tio.run/#)? Oh, and this is a snippet, not a function/program. So you should add `n=>` in front of it.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Done! Is it possible to simplify even further? TIL you can convert an int to string using `n+""`. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need the `bool f(long n)` or trailing semi-colon for lambda answers in C#, Java, etc. Just `n=>$"{BigInteger.Multiply(n,n)}".EndsWith(n+"")` is enough. :) And I almost forgot: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! :) Oh, and [here is your TIO-link converter to use just `n=>`](https://tio.run/##TY1Na8JAEIbv@yuG4GFD7V4US4l6UBQKtZQqeF42YzqQzMrORhDJb49rQHBu79czTt6dD9i3QlzB/ioRm0K9KvPTNhjISaFcbUXgN/gq2OamACTaSA4unkrYWWKdP1yAbctu/sVxNh2vvK/R8hJOsOh5sRxltxVVKcMKg9m1daRzfdU85rzLzIZLOVL81/yWZXn/YBVqQK49SyKZY6CI38SoTzp5FwzRHPzwSz87f2jLoZKnK9K8U13/OfmY3QE), by using a `System.Func`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Edited. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## R, 28 bytes

```
pryr::f(x^2%%10^nchar(x)==x)
```

Creates a function:

```
function (x) 
x^2%%10^nchar(x) == x
```

Takes the modulus of `x^2` such that we keep the last digits, which we compare to `x`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```js
n=>`${n*n}`.endsWith(n)
```

---

### Try it

Wrote this Snippet up on my phone, so please edit if it's not working correctly.

```js
f=
n=>`${n*n}`.endsWith(n)
oninput=_=>o.innerText=f(+i.value);o.innerText=f(i.value=1)
```

```html
<input id=i type=number><pre id=o>
```

Comment: This fails for **212890625** due to precision issues.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @Dennis; this was a quicky while on a smoke break so I (stupidly) only checked the test cases. Will ask for clarification on precision errors and delete when I get back to a computer, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
²ṚwṚ⁼1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Qpoc7Z5UD8aPGPYb///@3NDY3AwA)

Comment: Nice job outgolfing me.

Comment: @LeakyNun And I would've even tied Brachylog if I could've used `Ị`...

Answer (score 2):

## Kotlin, 36 bytes

```
fun a(i:Int)="${i*i}".endsWith("$i")
```

Answer (score 2):

## C, 77 + 4 (`-lm`) = 81 bytes

```c
#import<tgmath.h>
i;f(long double n){i=fmod(n*n,pow(10,(int)log10(n)+1))==n;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY1LDoIwFEXnrIJoSPoUhMZIUcSVOMFiS5P2lWCNA8LWrTJSGN5zfzyRnHu/VqazvTs7aWrX7tpLoEpBtEUZNvZ50/cQYVCVMLYhuMG4sy9Cs5godKCtpBlB2FKAqsJy9GlqaoUEhq7/BgRZRc0qFiQHKMdgYRWUFYxmxz07nMKoueIP5EvAJjAt/ZVgJvO5ZNOjf3Oha/nwiTYf)

Comment: Can use `n*n` for `pow(n,2)` and save 5 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 + 1 (-p) = 16 bytes

```perl
$_=$_**2=~/$_$/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lYlXkvLyLZOXyVeRf//f9N/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
²_ọæċ⁵$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///QpviHu3sPLzvS/ahxq8r///8tjc3NAA)

Positive number for yes, 0 for no.

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 41 bytes

```php
<?=preg_match("#$argn$#",bcpow($argn,2));
```

[PHP Sandbox Online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bd634da28574a838b859407ccbc0f911cb4729fc)

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 42 bytes

without Regex

```php
<?=strtr(bcpow($argn,2),[$argn=>X])[-1]>A;
```

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 44 bytes

Use the [levenshtein](http://php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) distance

```php
<?=!levenshtein($argn,bcpow($argn,2),0,1,1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>47</s> 33 bytes

14 bytes thanks to Martin Ender.

```
.+
$*
$
¶$`
\G1
$%_
M%`1
(.+)¶\1$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fT5tLRYtLhevQNpUErhh3Qy4V1XguX9UEQy4NPW3NQ9tiDFX@/zc3AwA)

Comment: I need to learn `$%`...

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyvil](https://github.com/dyvil/Dyvil), 26 bytes

```
x=>"\(x*x)".endsWith"\(x)"
```

Usage:

```
let f: int->boolean = x=>"\(x*x)".endsWith"\(x)"
print(f 20) // false
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 122 bytes

```
@set/an=%1,t=f=1
:l
@set/at+=t,f*=5,n/=10
@if %n% gtr 0 goto l
@cmd/cset/a"(!(%1%%t)|!(~-%1%%t))&(!(%1%%f)|!(~-%1%%f))
```

Algorithm is limited only by the integer type used for variables. In the case of Batch, this is 32-bit signed integers, so the maximum is 2147483647. Works by testing both n and n-1 for necessary powers of 2 and 5 as factors. (Except when n is 0 or 1, n and n-1 will have one factor each.)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [isaacg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20080/isaacg).

```
x_`^vz2_z
```

Returns 0 when the number is automorphic, anything else if it is not.

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=x_%60%5Evz2_z&input=8212890625&debug=0)

**Explanations**

```
x_`^vz2_z

   ^vz2      # Evaluate the input to a number, compute the square
  `          # Convert the squared number to a string
 _           # Reverse it
x      _z    # Find the index of the first occurrence of the reversed input in the reversed square. That's basically equivalent of doing an endswith() in Python
             # Implicit input of the index. If 0, then the reversed square starts with the reversed input
```

Comment: `\`` is convert to string.

Answer (score 1):

### [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 30 bytes

```
1&0}\{n;
:&(?\:::*&a*:&%={+}:&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/31DNoDamOs@ay0pNwz7GyspKSy1Ry0pN1bZau9ZK7f///7plCqaWloYWRoZGFpYGZkamAA), or watch it at the [fish playground](https://fishlanguage.com/playground)!

Assumes the input number *x* is already on the stack.

Explanation: The fish takes the quotient of *x*<sup>2</sup> by increasing powers of 10, and counts how many times this equals *x*. When the power of 10 gets larger than *x*, it prints the count and halts. The count will be 1 if *x* is automorphic, and 0 if it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 23 bytes

```
n->n^2%10^#digits(n)==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcrdBoBAEIbhW/mUaJlld9LfwXYjKSJlyRjVSVe/1dn78OpyRrtr2hCQxA4yc@HdnK9xj/dViglB0qJ6PKXADtAzyv1l9iPD9h2GMDqCJzChr9qG0LHnrncN15NJLw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Rexx (Regina)](http://www.rexx.org/), 48 bytes

```
numeric digits 25
arg n
say right(n*n,length(n))=n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0qtqPj/P680N7UoM1khJTM9s6RYwdSAK7EoXSGPqzixUqEoMz2jRCNPK08nJzUvvSRDI09T0zbv/39LY3MzMAEA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

```hs
f=reverse.show
g a=and$zipWith(==)(f a)$f$a^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCoAgEADQva9wcNBFrOb7joYoOOjUIzNRKejn7b2A9aQYe3dQ6KFSydRwv4MXCJgO@XFeuAUFoJUTqKWTuE/9Qk6QC6cmHcdGRfh1NGa2dus/)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [Data.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html), 42 bytes

```hs
g a=and$on(zipWith(==))(reverse.show)a$a^2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDsMgDADArzAwwIKSLJnYqn6hQ5VKVuoGK8Qg4zRSP0/vErQdc@501CJqbqAQ7ievSoX7ZiACv21h96P6IE0uRu@d4BelYWipXB4svKZ@AHGsQqz2Q1lRzPYcQ5iHYel/)

```hs
and.(on(zipWith(==))(reverse.show)<*>(^2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDsIwDADAr3RgsBmswsJCmBBfYEBUisA0FqkTOYZKfD7cpdjenHOXpRbz4Rw90uWjD5eifQ5RnwRF4Sf1Kp4gBEQw/rI1ppbKisftCaY9Yl@iaKgm6puXZGcb5tuO6DCO9/4H)

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/) + [Data.Function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Data-Function.html) + [Control.Monad](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html), 40 bytes

```hs
and.ap(on(zipWith(==))$reverse.show)(^2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LcihDsIwEABQz1dMTLTmMmZQVRAceoKw5MLKeqG7a64HJPx8MTz5EtZnzLnRVkStO6EhnF98NxLe/fMobCoZLsK4tDUgL4DFCbsvlYksuRC87zW@o9YINcnHu3n0bUPiUJTY@gdli9qt1z3AYRhu7Qc)

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```powershell
param([bigint]$a)""+$a*$a|% En* $a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY/LasJQEIbXOU8xyFgSq6ARrVKEQOm6UpcS5CROrCW3ngstaJ79dFJjxeX334apq29S@oPyfJRWihxmq5OrpZKFv02Oh2NpYpRBr/eIcoDy3IfXcgAoXSNE5AtvGPnjIaBRloI/mtxRyJTJXHe4nD7N7/xFOAkXy/E8nP3LAZyhDyfhYWmLhBQb9FNTamgPK8AdG4q0zQ3TA2bQxYS3XW9erDZV8ZZ8cjyOeMPb2DQlrdtm1xrR122RE@v2VzKk2sxl65nl9@uNrsdaIxrnfgE)

Could be 8 bytes shorted if passing a `bigint` as parameter was allowed

-2 bytes thanks to *Zaelin Goodman*!

Comment: suffix `n` with [PS7 only](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_numeric_literals?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: [34 bytes!](https://tio.run/##VY/LasJQEIbXOU8xyFgSq6ARrVKEQOm6UpcS5CROrCW3ngstaJ79dFJjxeX334apq29S@oPyfJRWihxmq5OrpZKFv02Oh2NpYpRBr/eIcoDy3IfXcgAoXSNE5AtvGPnjIaBRloI/mtxRyJTJXHe4nD7N7/xFOAkXy/E8nP3LAZyhDyfhYWmLhBQb9FNTamgPK8AdG4q0zQ3TA2bQxYS3XW9erDZV8ZZ8cjyOeMPb2DQlrdtm1xrR122RE@v2VzKk2sxl65nl9@uNrsdaIxrnfgE "PowerShell Core – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 3 bytes

```
²øf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJQciIsIiIsIsKyw7hmIiwiIiwiNjciXQ==)

First time using the `r` flag.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>40</s> 35 bytes

-@Nick A saved 5 bytes: use of `endswith()`

```python
lambda x:str(x*x).endswith(str(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqrikSKNCq0JTLzUvpbg8syRDAyyiqanwPy2/SCFTITNPoSgxLz1Vw9AAAjStuBQy0xTSNDI1rQqKMvNKgIz/AA)

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 31 bytes (Does not work for large numbers)

```python
lambda x:`x*x`[-len(`x`):]==`x`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCKqFCqyIhWjcnNU8joSJB0yrW1hZI/0/LL1LIVMjMUyhKzEtP1TA0MNC04lIoKMrMK9HI1EnTyNTU/A8A)

Comment: Doesn't work on `8212890625`  because ``x*x`` will end with "L". You can however save two bytes by removing the `f=` I think.

Comment: It would work in python 3 though, right?

Comment: You must use ``f=\`` not `f=/`...

Comment: @officialaimm no, the `` syntax doesn't work in Python 3.

Comment: I meant after replacing `` with `str()`

Comment: Yes that will work then.

Comment: Would using `endswith` and removing `s=str` not be shorter for python3?: `lambda x:str(x*x).endswith(str(x))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 15 bytes

```
{$^x²~~/$^x$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/WiWu4tCmujp9IK2iX/vfWqE4sVJBI87QwMBAUy@9KLVAQy1N8z8A)

Returns a truthy Match object for automorphic inputs, and a falsy Nil value for other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

### Clojure, 59 bytes

```
#(apply = true(map =(reverse(str %))(reverse(str(* % %)))))
```

This seems overly verbose.

Comment: Why not just go with `#(.endsWith(str(* % %))(str %))` ?

Comment: Oh true, it is so easy to forget about Java built-ins.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 10 bytes

```
UUVG36hXXn
```

This works for numbers up to `floor(sqrt(2^53))`, as per `double` precision limitations.

Output is a positive number (which is truthy) if automorphic, or empty (which is falsy) if not.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PzQ0zN3YLCMiIu//f3VLY3MzdQA)

#### Explanation

Funny that this answer uses the two overloaded versions of `U`: with string input it evaluates as a number, and with number input it computes the square.

```
U      % Implicitly input a string. Evaluate as a number
U      % Square of number
V      % Convert number to string representation
G      % Push input string again
36h    % Post-pend '$'
XX     % Regexp match. Gives cell array of matching substrings.
n      % Number of elements. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 36 bytes

```
n->(n.multiply(n)+"").endsWith(n+"")
```

Input is a `java.math.BigInteger`, output a `boolean`.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##lY4/b8IwEMX3fIpTJlsVFqQqfxS1QzcGWBg6VB2MY4JT@2zFFypU5bOnprRiJdLd8N7T7@418iQnPmhsqs/BuOBbgiZ5wkk6ildTr5F0rdsyU1bGCBtp8DsDMMluD1Jp2F4kwN57qyWCYjcIkJcp7NOmiSTJKNgCwjMMOHlhKFxnyQR7Zsgf8pwLjVV8M3RkeJFDeSVDt7eJ/Dtw8qYCl3qwHbUG6/cPkPxaYneOpJ3wHYmQIrKYfiiG@gturVg@zTn/bXY3MRtNFKOJ1eNiPhpaFrNiuZrOi6d/tM/64Qc)

```
n->                   // Method with BigInteger parameter and boolean return-type 
  (n.multiply(n)+"")  //  Return if the String representation of n*n
   .endsWith(n+"")    //  ends with the String representation of n
                      // End of method (implicit / single-line body)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 37 bytes

```
[ [ sq ] keep [ present ] bi@ tail? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcyxDoIwFEbhnaf4n8BADQg6yGZYWIgT6VDJNTZCLe1lIMZnL3VgO/mG81QDf1y4d017O2NS/MKbnKER1pEnw/A0L2QG8n9hXq3TUS9J8kWKDALV8VSgFJkoq7QQOX6hRw8/Q8YV2dj7SuKha7DS4xUyTMriEDY)

- `[ sq ] keep` Square the input, but also retain a copy of the input on top of the stack. (Identical length to `dup sq swap`.)
- `[ present ] bi@` Convert both numbers to strings.
- `tail?` Is top-of-stack a suffix of next-on-stack?

Answer (score 0):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
§€d(ṫd□
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATIAzf9odXNr/23igoH/wqfigqxkKOG5q2TilqH///9bMCwxLDIsOTM3Niw4MjEyODkwNjI1XQ)

````
§        # fork:
 €       # index of arg1 in arg2, or zero if absent:
  d      # arg1: digits of input
   (     # arg2: 
    ṫ    # tails = all suffixes of
     d   # digits of
      □  # square of input
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## ARM Thumb machine code, 20 bytes

```
01 22 0a 23 5a 43 81 1a fc d2 40 43 80 1a fd d2
08 1a 70 47
```

Since ARM uses 32-bit arithmetic, this can only handle up to \$2^{16}-1\$. This is OK according to the OP's comment, and the calculations would still be correct with larger integers (which is confirmed with equivalent AArch64 code)...although it would be pretty slow due to the subtraction loop.

```c
    .syntax unified
    .arch armv7-a
    .thumb
    .globl  automorphic
    .thumb_func
    // input: r0, output: r0 (zero for true)
    // C calling convention
automorphic:
    // Calculate power of 10 larger than the digits
    // by repeatedly multiplying by 10.
    movs    r2, #1                                         @ pow10 = 1;
    movs    r3, #10                                        @ TEN = 10;
.Llog10:                                                   @ do {
    // Multiply by 10.
    muls    r2, r3                                         @     pow10 *= TEN;
    // Multiple purpose:
    //   - The SUBS sets the flags as if we were doing
    //        do { pow10 *= TEN; } while (x >= pow10);
    //   - This saves x to another register so we can square
    //     with narrow MULS which overwrites the source.
    //   - This pre-subtracts pow10 to compensate for the
    //     below modulo loop which runs an extra iteration.
    subs    r1, r0, r2                                     @    tmp = x - pow10;
    bhs     .Llog10                                        @ } while (x >= pow10);
.Llog10_end:
    // Square x.
    muls    r0, r0                                         @ x2 = x * x;
    // Naive modulo loop by repeated subtraction, which is
    // always shorter than udiv+mul+sub. As stated before,
    // this actually calculates x2 % pow10 - pow10.        @ mod = x2;
.Lmodulo:                                                  @ do {
    subs    r0, r2                                         @     x2 = mod; mod = x2 - pow10;
    bhs     .Lmodulo                                       @ } while (x2 >= pow10);
    // Subtract to get a 3-way comparison, with 0 being true
    subs    r0, r1, r0                                     @ result = tmp - mod;
    // Return
    bx      lr                                             @ return result;
```

This function uses the AAPCS calling convention, and can be called from C.

It returns zero for true and non-zero for false.

```c
int32_t automorphic(uint32_t x);
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 83 bytes

```
\N:-S is N*N,N+D,S+P,prefix(D,P).
N+[H|D]:-N>9,H is N mod 10,R is N//10,R+D.
N+[N].
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P8bPSjdYIbNYwU/LT8dP20UnWDtAp6AoNS2zQsNFJ0BTj8tPO9qjxiXWStfPzlLHA6xUITc/RcHQQCcIzNPXBzG1XcBK/WL1gIYa6HHFGAKxERBbGpub6QEA)

For whatever reason the last test case (`8212890625`) doesn't work on TIO, but it does work everywhere else I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
²$ø>
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVDMiVCMiUyNCVDMyVCOCUzRSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTElMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwVHJ1ZSUwQTIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwRmFsc2UlMEE5Mzc2JTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMFRydWUlMEE4MjEyODkwNjI1JTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMFRydWUmZmxhZ3M9Qw==)

##### Explanation

```python
²$ø>  # Implicit input
²     # The input squared...
  ø>  # ...ends with...
 $    # ...the input?
      # Implicit output
```